# Cerberus accept as valid the empty values

Tags: python, flask, cerberus

Trying to get this validation as acceptable  `True`, where any of the fields could be `empty: True` (default i know), but when not empty than all the sequential conditionals must apply.

SCHEMA `v = Validator()`

```
schm = {'l_addrsch': {'type': 'string', 'empty': True, 'allowed': ['m', 'o', 'e', 'M', 'O', 'E'], 'dependencies': ['l_nrefaddr', 'l_refaddr']},
    'l_nrefaddr': {'type': 'integer', 'empty': True, 'dependencies': ['l_addrsch', 'l_refaddr']},
    'l_refaddr': {'type': 'integer', 'empty': True, 'dependencies': ['l_addrsch', 'l_nrefaddr']}}
```

POST `val = v.validate(p, schema)`

```
{ 
"l_addrsch" : "",
"l_nrefaddr" : "",
"l_refaddr" :  ""
}
```

RESPONSE

```
    [
    {
        "l_addrsch": [
            "unallowed value "
        ],
        "l_nrefaddr": [
            "must be of integer type"
        ],
        "l_refaddr": [
            "must be of integer type"
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope i was not too confuse.

EDIT 1: 
 tried this as mentioned on normalizing rules 'default' :

```
schema = {'l_addrsch': {'type': 'string', 'default': '', 'allowed': ['', 'm', 'o', 'e', 'M', 'O', 'E'], 'dependencies': ['l_nrefaddr', 'l_refaddr']},
                'l_nrefaddr': {'type': 'integer', 'default': 0, 'dependencies': ['l_addrsch', 'l_refaddr']},
                'l_refaddr': {'type': 'integer', 'default': 0, 'dependencies': ['l_addrsch', 'l_nrefaddr']}
```

POST:

```
   { "l_addrsch" : "",
    "l_nrefaddr" : "",
    "l_refaddr" :  ""}
```

But seems that i still missing something to get it working for the integers

```
[
    {
        "l_nrefaddr": [
            "must be of integer type"
        ],
        "l_refaddr": [
            "must be of integer type"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: It's propably a good idea to set all fields as `required`, which is semantically the same like the inter-`dependencies`, but simpler imo.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#empty):

> If `False`, validation of an iterable value will fail if it is empty.
>   **Setting it to True manually is pointless** as it behaves like omitting
>   the rule at all

To set default values, use the normalization rule instead.
http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/normalization-rules.html#default-values

Something like this:

```
'kind': {'type': 'string', 'default': ''}
```

Comment: See my EDIT 1 below - where i try the 'default' - it works if i had the '' to 'alowed' list of values but then fails with the integers . Missing something here. Thanks

Comment: 0 can be written without a fractional component it is considered to be an integer.

Comment: the same {'type': 'integer', 'default': 1000,  'dependencies': ['l_addrsch', 'l_refaddr']}

Answer (score 0):

The validation fails for two reasons:

1. `''` is not defined as `allowed` value, this ruleset should achieve what you want for the `l_addrsch` field:

   `'l_addrsch': {'type': string, 'allowed': ('', 'm', 'o', 'e', 'M', 'O', 'E'), 'required': True}`

   *Update*: With Cerberus 1.2 it will be possible to have an empty field (if permitted) that will not be checked for allowed values (see [this](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/pull/342/commits/41d4e47012122a58c71e78f51d588c3fe9c5105b) commit).
2. As a string (`''`) is passed as value for the two other fields, it will of course fail with a `type` constrained to `integer`. You should add a [coercion](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/normalization-rules.html#value-coercion) of the input value, if `''` always means `0`.